# Cassandra timeseries datamodel

Tags: nosql, cassandra, datamodel, phpcassa, cassandra-jdbc

Let assume 10 devices(dev01,dev02,dev03..etc).

It send data with some interval time,we collect those data,so our data schema is

```
 dev01      :int
 signalname :string
 signaltime :date/time[with YY-MM-DD HHMMSS.mm]
 Extradata  :String
```

I want to push data into cassandra ,which way is best to store those data?

My Query is Like ,

1 Need to retrive device based current day data,or with some date range?

2 5 Device current day data?

I am not sure the following way to store data into cassadra is best model

```
Standard columnfamily Name:signalname
row key                   :dev01
columnname                :timeseries(20120801124204)[YYMMDD HHMMSS]
columnvalue               :Json data
columnname                :timeseries(20120801124205)[YYMMDD HHMMSS][next second data]
columnvalue               :Json data

row key               :dev02
columnname            :timeseries(20120801124204)[YYMMDD HHMMSS]
columnvalue           :Json data
columnname            :timeseries(20120801124205)[YYMMDD HHMMSS][next second data]
columnvalue           :Json data

Or  

Super columnfamily   :signalname
row key              :Clientid1

supercolumnname      :dev01
columnname           :timeseries(20120801124204)[YYMMDD HHMMSS]
columnvalue          :Json data

supercolumnname      :dev02
columnname           :timeseries(20120801124204)[YYMMDD HHMMSS]
columnvalue          :Json data


row key              :Clientid2

supercolumnname      :dev03
columnname           :timeseries(20120801124204)[YYMMDD HHMMSS]
columnvalue          :Json data

supercolumnname      :dev04
columnname           :timeseries(20120801124204)[YYMMDD HHMMSS]
columnvalue          :Json data
```

kindly help me out regarding this issue,
Any other Way?

Thanks&Regards,
Kannadhasan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see 3 issues with your approach here which I will address below:

- super column families,
- thrift vs cql3,
- json data as cell values.

Before you go ahead: the use **super column families** is discouraged. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198419/cassandra-column-family-vs-super-column-family). Composite keys (as described below) are the way to go.

Also, you might need to [read up on CQL3](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3), since **thrift is a legacy API** since 1.2.

Instead of storing json data, you may make use of [native collection data types like lists, and maps etc](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=cql_cli/using/collections#cassandra/ddl/ddl_anatomy_table_c.html#concept_ds_qnt_w2z_zj). If you still want to work with JSON, there is [improved JSON support in in Cassandra since version 2.2](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-2-json-support).

In general, it is pretty straightforward to query per device and per timeperiod:

- you row key would be the device id and the column key a timeuuid
- To avoid hot spots, you could add "bucket" counters to the row key (create a composite row/partition key) to rotate the nodes
- You can then query for time ranges if you know the row/device id.

Alternatively you could use your signal type as a row key (and timeuuid/timestamp as a column key) if you want to query data for multiple devices (but one event type) at once. Read more on timeseries data in cassandra in [this blog entry](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.de/2013/05/time-series-based-queries-in-cassandra.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks omnibear,so you suggested to use composite columnfamily primary key as device id,timestamp followed some column name,column value

Comment: while we using cql3 to read single row key having timeseries 10000 record it is taking nearly 8 min for 4 clumn ,performance is slow

Comment: Could you update your question above to reflect those latest changes? For instance, could you give your CQL3 "create table" statement? Otherwise, it is hard to give a helpful answer.

Comment: _Composite row key_ means: two values are combined into one row/partition key, for instance "deviceid" and "bucket". `create table ..... primary key((deviceid, bucket), signaltime)`. All column keys (here: signaltime) are by default _composite column keys_ if there is more than one (this is not the case here). If oyu have a composite column key, then you can only run range queries on the last column key. The first has to be queried using an EQ operator.

Comment: CREATE COLUMNFAMILY deviceidcomposite(did varchar,signalid varchar,lat varchar,lan varchar,timestamp varchar,PRIMARY KEY (did,timestamp))

Comment: 1) Change the "timestamp" varchar into a timeUUID or a timestamp data type. 2) Use this column key in your query and re-check the performance. (For instance, `select * from deviceidcomposite where did = 0 and timestamp > 1375429645 and timestamp <  1375160400;`) 3) If you use timestamp/timeuuid, always use UTC+0 as a timezone to avoid problems in a distributed environment.